# Terminal Browsing Problem

Tags: browser, terminal

Why does the code not open the proper Google page?

```
elinks http://google.com/search/?q=`echo "ERROR database is being accessed by other users" | sed 's# #+#g'`
```

Comment: what error are you getting when you run this from a terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you added an extraneous `/` after `search`. Try this instead:

```
 elinks http://google.com/search?q=`echo "ERROR database is being accessed by other users" | sed 's# #+#g'`
```